# How can i use the return value of a private static method (extension of object) in a different method in that same class? (java)

Tags: java

I have a java project with 3 classes. 1 class is used as a static private method in another class. I need to add the results of that method to be added to a list in another method within that class.

Is there anyone who can send me in a good direction?

Comment: Please show the classes and methods, you can omit everything else for brevity.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Where is declaration of variable `scores` in method `wordScore()`?

Comment: @Abra i added them.

Comment: What is the purpose of the array `tileCounts`? I don't see it used anywhere.

Comment: @AmalK It was provided my by assignment; at first it is similar to counts[], but when you use letters, you subtract them there. (this is a game of scrabble)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want the implementation of method `validWords()`. The following works for me.

```java
public static List<WordScore> validWords(final List<String> wordList, final int[] tileCounts) {
    return wordList.stream()
                   .map(word -> wordScore(word, tileCounts))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The above code uses the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) that was added in Java 8. You can also refer to the lesson entitled [Aggregate Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) in Oracle's Java tutorials.

Method [stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) that is inherited by interface `java.util.List` returns a "stream" of all the elements in `wordList`. Each element is a string.

Method `map` takes a single parameter which is a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html). A functional interface can be implemented by a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). The method that needs to be implemented takes a single string parameter and returns a `WordScore` object.

Method `collect()` also takes a single parameter that is a functional interface. Utility class `Collectors` contains an implementation that returns a `List` that contains all the elements in the stream. In this case the stream contains `WordScore` elements. Hence `collect()` in the above code returns the list that you want the method `validWords()` to return.

If this is not what you are looking for, let me know and I will delete it.

Comment: @user14418746 a word of advice for future questions. You should indicate that your question is about a homework assignment and you should also state what limitations, if ant, are imposed on the solution you are to provide. I assume that you have not yet learned about the stream API and therefore not allowed to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Member functions of the same class can call and pass data to each other. You just need to call `wordScore()` from `validWords()` for each string in the list.

```
public static List<WordScore> validWords (final List<String> wordList, final int[] tileCounts) {
    List<WordScore> results = new ArrayList<WordScore>();
    for(String word : wordList) {
        results.add(wordScore(word, tileCounts));
    }
    return results;
}
```

This is the simple way. @Abra's code also works, it uses the Stream API introduced in Java 8. Java 8 has also introduced lambda expressions which will help simplify your `Comparator`:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<WordScore>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(final WordScore wsA, final WordScore wsB)
            {
                return (wsA.score() == wsB.score())
                        ? 0
                        : (wsA.score() > wsB.score()) ? -1 : 1;
            }
        });
```

This can be rewritten as:

```
Collections.sort(list, (wsA) -> (wsA.score() == wsB.score())
                        ? 0
                        : (wsA.score() > wsB.score()) ? -1 : 1);
```

This works because `Comparator` is a functional interface, an interface that contains only one method `compare()`. Instead of creating an anonymous class and overriding `compare()`, what you do is simply specify the arguments in parantheses (type isn't required, the compiler is smart enough to infer them) followed by the `->` operator. After this, you specify the return value, the `return` keyword can also be omitted.

You also don't have to do these multiple condition checks, simply return the difference of the scores:

```
Collections.sort(list, (wsA, wsB) ->  wsA.score() - wsB.score() );
```

Comment: your first piece of code gives me an error as it expects a method call.

Comment: one more question: it only needs to add the words that do not return null in wordScore. Where should I implement that? When calling from main or should that be added in the method?

Comment: @user14418746 I'm not quite sure how Scrabble works but where the implementation would go is a matter of intention behind the method. If you expect the method to filter it out or you're gonna need to filter it multiple times, it's better to have the method do it. If you want a one to one mapping between the input and output list wherein say `results.get(3)` represents `wordList.get(3)`, then it's better to not filter it out.